# Oracle - cumulative counts within chain of records

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an oracle table DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW with below columns and sample data. Data below shows

-dmc_id ='408' there are 2109 devices which are having firmware_version='RT1' and it is the first firmware_version because image_prerequisite is null for this firmware_image.

-dmc_id ='408' there are 40 devices which are having firmware_version='RT2' moved from "RT1" and so on.

The requirement is to create the chain of firmware_versions and the count of devices moving through the chain. For example:

```
Firmware_version movement is RT1-->RT2-->RT3-->RT4
so the count of devices moved from RT1 to RT4 is (RT1+RT2+RT3+RT4)
count of devices moved from RT2 to RT4 is (RT2+RT3+RT4)
count of devices moved from RT3 to RT4 is (RT3+RT4)
count of devices at last firmware_version is RT4
```

Below is the input data in table DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW

```
   +-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
device_count| dmc_id| firmware_version| cg_id           |image_prerequisite| count_within_dmcid|
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 40        | 408   |RT2              |0                |RT1               | 24028             |
| 24        | 408   |RT3              |0                |RT2               | 24028             |
| 18        | 408   |RT4              |0                |RT3               | 24028             |
| 2109      | 408   |RT1              |0                |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 1422   |RT1              |0                |null              | 7                 |
| 1         | 1422   |RT2              |0                |RT1               | 7                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000041 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000334 |null              | 2                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000359 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000441 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000001885 |null              | 2                 |
| 4         | 408   |SVP01            |0                |null              | 24028             |
| 11        | 408   |Sanity01         |0                |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 408   |Sanity1          |0                |null              | 24028             |
| 6         | 408   |TB_HT01          |0                |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 408   |TEST_1           |0                |null              | 24028             |
| 5         | 408   |TK_ST001         |0                |null              | 24028             |
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Query that I have executed:

```
SELECT
chain,
firmware_version as fw,
device_count as cnt,
dmc_id,
cg_id,
count_within_dmcid,
sum( device_count ) over ( partition by dmc_id, cg_id order by lev desc ) as cumm
FROM (
    select t.* , level lev, 
           sys_connect_by_path( firmware_version, '/' ) as chain
    from DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW t
    START WITH image_prerequisite IS null
    CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version=image_prerequisite
                   AND PRIOR dmc_id = dmc_id
                   AND PRIOR cg_id  = cg_id 
) x
order by dmc_id, cg_id, lev desc
;
```

Results Query is returning:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----+------+----------------+------------------+----+
chain             |fw       |cnt  |dmc_id|  cg_id         |count_within_dmcid|cumm|
+-----------------+---------+-----+------+----------------+------------------+----+
|/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4 | RT4     |   18| 408  |  0             | 24028            |  18|
|/RT1/RT2/RT3     | RT3     |   24| 408  |  0             | 24028            |  42|
|/RT1/RT2         | RT2     |   40| 408  |  0             | 24028            |  82|
|/Sanity1         |Sanity1  |   1 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |2219|
|/TB_HT01         |TB_HT01  |   6 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |2219|
|/Sanity01        |Sanity01 |   11| 408  |  0             | 24028            |2219|
|/SVP01           |SVP01    |   4 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |2219|
|/RT1             | RT1     |2109 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |2219|
|/TEST_1          |TEST_1   |   1 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |2219|
|/TK_ST001        |TK_ST001 |   5 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |2219|
|/RT1             |RT1      |   1 | 408  |HFOTA-0000000041|     1            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000000334|     2            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000000359|     1            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000000441|     1            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000001885|     2            |  1 |
|/RT1/RT2         |RT2      |1    |1422  |    0           |     7            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    |1422  |  0             |     7            |  2 |
+-----------------+---------+-----+------+----------------+------------------+----+
```

Expected Results:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----+------+----------------+------------------+----+
chain             |fw       |cnt  |dmc_id|  cg_id         |count_within_dmcid|cumm|
+-----------------+---------+-----+------+----------------+------------------+----+
|/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4 | RT4     |   18| 408  |  0             | 24028            |  18|
|/RT1/RT2/RT3     | RT3     |   24| 408  |  0             | 24028            |  42|
|/RT1/RT2         | RT2     |   40| 408  |  0             | 24028            |  82|
|/Sanity1         |Sanity1  |   1 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |  1 |
|/TB_HT01         |TB_HT01  |   6 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |  6 |
|/Sanity01        |Sanity01 |   11| 408  |  0             | 24028            | 11 |
|/SVP01           |SVP01    |   4 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |  4 |
|/RT1             | RT1     |2109 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |2191|
|/TEST_1          |TEST_1   |   1 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |  1 |
|/TK_ST001        |TK_ST001 |   5 | 408  |  0             | 24028            |  5 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |   1 | 408  |HFOTA-0000000041|     1            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000000334|     2            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000000359|     1            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000000441|     1            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    | 408  |HFOTA-0000001885|     2            |  1 |
|/RT1/RT2         |RT2      |1    |1422  |  0             |     7            |  1 |
|/RT1             |RT1      |1    |1422  |  0             |     7            |  2 |
+-----------------+---------+-----+------+----------------+------------------+----+
```

Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

---

Another scenario with the split chains -

Input data in DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW table.

```
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
device_count| dmc_id| firmware_version| cg_id           |image_prerequisite| count_within_dmcid|
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 5         | 3345  |SU.B             |0000000000000000 |SU.A              | 93                |
| 6         | 3345  |SU.C             |0000000000000000 |SU.B              | 93                |
| 8         | 3345  |SU.D             |0000000000000000 |SU.C              | 93                |
| 8         | 3345  |SU.E             |0000000000000000 |SU.C              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.F             |0000000000000000 |SU.D              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.F             |0000000000000000 |SU.E              | 93                |
| 10        | 3345  |SU.G             |0000000000000000 |SU.F              | 93                |
| 11        | 3345  |SU.H             |0000000000000000 |SU.F              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.I             |0000000000000000 |SU.G              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.I             |0000000000000000 |SU.H              | 93                |
| 5         | 3345  |SU.A             |0000000000000000 |null              | 93                |
| 40        | 408   |RT2              |0000000000000000 |RT1               | 24028             |
| 24        | 408   |RT3              |0000000000000000 |RT2               | 24028             |
| 18        | 408   |RT4              |0000000000000000 |RT3               | 24028             |
| 2109      | 408   |RT1              |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 142   |RT1              |0000000000000000 |null              | 7                 |
| 1         | 142   |RT2              |0000000000000000 |RT1               | 7                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000041 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000334 |null              | 2                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000359 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000441 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000001885 |null              | 2                 |
| 4         | 408   |SVP01            |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 11        | 408   |Sanity01         |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 408   |Sanity1          |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 6         | 408   |TB_HT01          |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 408   |TEST_1           |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 5         | 408   |TK_ST001         |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

This query is breaking in the path split scenario data.

```
         SU.A (5)                    -- Level 1         
             |                                  
         SU.B (5)                    -- Level 2         
             |                                  
         SU.C (6)                    -- Level 3         
         /     \                                
(8) SU.D     SU.E (8)                -- Level 4         
         \     /                                
         SU.F (20)                   -- Level 5         
         /      \
(10) SU.G    SU.H (11)               -- Level 6
         \      /
         SU.I (20)                   -- Level 7
```

Query used:

```
SELECT chain,
       root_fw,
       firmware_version,
       device_count,
       dmc_id,
       charging_group_id,
       count_within_dmcid,
       SUM(device_count) over(PARTITION BY dmc_id, cg_id, root_fw ORDER BY lev DESC),
       lev
FROM   (SELECT t.*,
               LEVEL lev,
               sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/') AS chain,
               connect_by_root(firmware_version) root_fw
        FROM   dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw t
        START  WITH image_prerequisite IS NULL
        CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version = image_prerequisite
            AND    PRIOR dmc_id = dmc_id
            AND    PRIOR cg_id = cg_id) x
ORDER  BY dmc_id,
          cg_id,
          lev DESC;
```

Ouput query is returning:

```
+-----------------------------------+--------+--------+-------------+------+----------------+------------------+----+---+
chain                               |root_fw |fw      |device_count |dmc_id|  cg_id         |count_within_dmcid|cumm|lev|
+-----------------------------------+--------+--------+-------------+------+----------------+------------------+----+---+
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.F/SU.G/SU.I|SU.A    |SU.I    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |80  |7  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.E/SU.F/SU.H/SU.I|SU.A    |SU.I    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |80  |7  | 
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.E/SU.F/SU.G/SU.I|SU.A    |SU.I    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |80  |7  | 
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.F/SU.H/SU.I|SU.A    |SU.I    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |80  |7  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.E/SU.F/SU.G     |SU.A    |SU.G    | 10          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |122 |6  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.F/SU.G     |SU.A    |SU.G    | 10          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |122 |6  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.F/SU.H     |SU.A    |SU.H    | 11          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |122 |6  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.E/SU.F/SU.H     |SU.A    |SU.H    | 11          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |122 |6  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.E/SU.F          |SU.A    |SU.F    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |162 |5  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.F          |SU.A    |SU.F    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |162 |5  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.E               |SU.A    |SU.E    | 8           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |178 |4  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D               |SU.A    |SU.D    | 8           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |178 |4  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C                    |SU.A    |SU.C    | 6           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |184 |3  |
|/SU.A/SU.B                         |SU.A    |SU.B    | 5           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |189 |2  |
|/SU.A                              |SU.A    |SU.A    | 5           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |194 |1  |
|/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4                   |RT1     |RT4     | 18          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |18  |4  |
|/RT1/RT2/RT3                       |RT1     |RT3     | 24          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |42  |3  |
|/RT1/RT2                           |RT1     |RT2     | 40          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |82  |2  |
|/Sanity1                           |Sanity1 |Sanity1 | 1           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |1   |1  |  
|/TB_HT01                           |TB_HT01 |TB_HT01 | 6           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |6   |1  |
|/Sanity01                          |Sanity01|Sanity01| 11          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |11  |1  |
|/SVP01                             |SVP01   |SVP01   | 4           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |4   |1  |
|/RT1                               |RT1     |RT1     | 2109        |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |2191|1  |
|/TEST_1                            |TEST_1  |TEST_1  | 1           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |1   |1  |
|/TK_ST001                          |TK_ST001|TK_ST001| 5           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |5   |1  |
|/RT1                               |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000041|1                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                               |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000334|2                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                               |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000359|1                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                               |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000441|1                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                               |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000001885|2                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1/RT2                           |RT1     |RT2     | 1           |1422  |0000000000000000|7                 |1   |2  |
|/RT1                               |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |1422  |0000000000000000|7                 |2   |1  |
+-----------------------------------+--------+--------+-------------+------+----------------+------------------+----+---+
```

Chain and cumulative counts are coming correct for regural chains A - B- C- D, but if we have split chains then it is doing summary of all the chain generated.

```
SU.A - 93   A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I
SU.B - 88   B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I
SU.C - 83   C+D+E+F+G+H+I
SU.D - 0    (Cummulative count will be zero if we have two or more FW at same level)
SU.E - 0    (Cummulative count will be zero if we have two or more FW at same level)
SU.F - 61   F+G+H+I
SU.G - 0    Cummulative count will be zero if we have two or more FW at same level)
SU.H - 0    Cummulative count will be zero if we have two or more FW at same level)
SU.I - 20   I
```

Expected output in this split scenario:

```
+---------------------------------------------+--------+--------+-------------+------+----------------+------------------+----+---+
chain                                         |root_fw |fw      |device_count |dmc_id|  cg_id         |count_within_dmcid|cumm|lev|
+---------------------------------------------+--------+--------+-------------+------+----------------+------------------+----+---+
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.E/SU.F/SU.G/SU.H/SU.I|SU.A    |SU.I    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |20  |7  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.E/SU.F/SU.G/SU.H/    |SU.A    |SU.H    | 11          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |0   |6  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.E/SU.F/SU.G          |SU.A    |SU.G    | 10          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |0   |6  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.E/SU.F               |SU.A    |SU.F    | 20          |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |61  |5  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D/SU.E                    |SU.A    |SU.E    | 8           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |0   |4  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D                         |SU.A    |SU.D    | 8           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |0   |4  |
|/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C                              |SU.A    |SU.C    | 6           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |83  |3  |
|/SU.A/SU.B                                   |SU.A    |SU.B    | 5           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |88  |2  |
|/SU.A                                        |SU.A    |SU.A    | 5           |3345  |0000000000000000|93                |93  |1  |
|/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4                             |RT1     |RT4     | 18          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |18  |4  |
|/RT1/RT2/RT3                                 |RT1     |RT3     | 24          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |42  |3  |
|/RT1/RT2                                     |RT1     |RT2     | 40          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |82  |2  |
|/Sanity1                                     |Sanity1 |Sanity1 | 1           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |1   |1  |  
|/TB_HT01                                     |TB_HT01 |TB_HT01 | 6           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |6   |1  |
|/Sanity01                                    |Sanity01|Sanity01| 11          |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |11  |1  |
|/SVP01                                       |SVP01   |SVP01   | 4           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |4   |1  |
|/RT1                                         |RT1     |RT1     | 2109        |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |2191|1  |
|/TEST_1                                      |TEST_1  |TEST_1  | 1           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |1   |1  |
|/TK_ST001                                    |TK_ST001|TK_ST001| 5           |408   |0000000000000000|24028             |5   |1  |
|/RT1                                         |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000041|1                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                                         |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000334|2                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                                         |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000359|1                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                                         |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000000441|1                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1                                         |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |408   |HFOTA-0000001885|2                 |1   |1  |
|/RT1/RT2                                     |RT1     |RT2     | 1           |1422  |0000000000000000|7                 |1   |2  |
|/RT1                                         |RT1     |RT1     | 1           |1422  |0000000000000000|7                 |2   |1  |
+---------------------------------------------+--------+--------+-------------+------+----------------+------------------+----+---+
```

Comment: `partition by .... charging_group_id` - you don't mention a charging_group_id column in your sample data? Please could you update your question to include the column? Also your actual and expected outputs don't quite match up with your input data - eg. the cg_id and count_within_dmcid columns don't match for some of the rows (e.g. the HFOTA rows)

Comment: @Boneist Thanks for the response!
I have updated my question. Please help to find a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're missing is partitioning on the root firmware_version, which you can get by using `connect_by_root()`, like so:

```
WITH dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw AS (SELECT 40 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT2' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT1' image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 24 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT3' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT2' image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 18 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT4' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT3' image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 2109 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 1422 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 7 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 1422 dmc_id, 'RT2' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT1' image_prerequisite, 7 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA1' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 1 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA2' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 2 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA3' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 1 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA4' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 1 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA5' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 2 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 4 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'SVP01' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 11 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'Sanity01' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'Sanity1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 6 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'TB_HT01' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'TEST_1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 5 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'TK_ST001' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual)
SELECT chain,
       root_fw,
       firmware_version AS fw,
       device_count AS cnt,
       dmc_id,
       cg_id,
       lev,
       count_within_dmcid,
       SUM(device_count) over(PARTITION BY dmc_id, cg_id, root_fw ORDER BY lev DESC) AS cumm
FROM   (SELECT t.*,
               LEVEL lev,
               sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/') AS chain,
               connect_by_root(firmware_version) root_fw
        FROM   dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw t
        START  WITH image_prerequisite IS NULL
        CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version = image_prerequisite
            AND    PRIOR dmc_id = dmc_id
            AND    PRIOR cg_id = cg_id) x
ORDER  BY dmc_id,
          cg_id,
          lev DESC;
```

Which gives the results:

```
CHAIN             ROOT_FW  FW              CNT     DMC_ID CG_ID         LEV COUNT_WITHIN_DMCID       CUMM
----------------- -------- -------- ---------- ---------- ------ ---------- ------------------ ----------
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4  RT1      RT4              18        408 0000            4              24028         18
/RT1/RT2/RT3      RT1      RT3              24        408 0000            3              24028         42
/RT1/RT2          RT1      RT2              40        408 0000            2              24028         82
/Sanity1          Sanity1  Sanity1           1        408 0000            1              24028          1
/TB_HT01          TB_HT01  TB_HT01           6        408 0000            1              24028          6
/Sanity01         Sanity01 Sanity01         11        408 0000            1              24028         11
/SVP01            SVP01    SVP01             4        408 0000            1              24028          4
/RT1              RT1      RT1            2109        408 0000            1              24028       2191
/TEST_1           TEST_1   TEST_1            1        408 0000            1              24028          1
/TK_ST001         TK_ST001 TK_ST001          5        408 0000            1              24028          5
/RT1              RT1      RT1               1        408 HFOTA1          1                  1          1
/RT1              RT1      RT1               1        408 HFOTA2          1                  2          1
/RT1              RT1      RT1               1        408 HFOTA3          1                  1          1
/RT1              RT1      RT1               1        408 HFOTA4          1                  1          1
/RT1              RT1      RT1               1        408 HFOTA5          1                  2          1
/RT1/RT2          RT1      RT2               1       1422 0000            2                  7          1
/RT1              RT1      RT1               1       1422 0000            1                  7          2
```

---

ETA:

With the additional requirement to handle cases where firmewares are at the same level as each other, I *think* this does what you're after:

```
WITH dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw AS (SELECT 40 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT2' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT1' image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 24 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT3' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT2' image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 18 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT4' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT3' image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 2109 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 1422 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 7 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 1422 dmc_id, 'RT2' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'RT1' image_prerequisite, 7 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA1' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 1 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA2' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 2 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA3' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 1 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA4' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 1 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'RT1' firmware_version, 'HFOTA5' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 2 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 4 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'SVP01' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 11 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'Sanity01' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'Sanity1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 6 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'TB_HT01' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'TEST_1' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 5 device_count, 408 dmc_id, 'TK_ST001' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 24028 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 5 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.B' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.A' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 6 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.C' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.B' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 8 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.D' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.C' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 8 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.E' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.C' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 20 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.F' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.D' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 20 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.F' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.E' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 10 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.G' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.F' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 11 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.H' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.F' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 20 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.I' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.G' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 20 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.I' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, 'SU.H' image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 5 device_count, 3345 dmc_id, 'SU.A' firmware_version, '0000' cg_id, NULL image_prerequisite, 93 count_within_dmcid FROM dual),
                            t1 AS (SELECT device_count,
                                          dmc_id,
                                          CASE WHEN COUNT(image_prerequisite) OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, cg_id, image_prerequisite) > 1
                                                    THEN listagg(firmware_version, '~') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY firmware_version) OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, cg_id, image_prerequisite)
                                               ELSE firmware_version
                                          END firmware_version,
                                          cg_id,
                                          image_prerequisite,
                                          count_within_dmcid
                                   FROM   dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw),
                            t2 AS (SELECT sum(device_count) device_count,
                                          dmc_id,
                                          firmware_version,
                                          cg_id,
                                          image_prerequisite,
                                          count_within_dmcid
                                   FROM   t1
                                   GROUP BY dmc_id,
                                            firmware_version,
                                            cg_id,
                                            image_prerequisite,
                                            count_within_dmcid),
                            t3 AS (SELECT t.*,
                                          LEVEL lev,
                                          sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/') AS chain,
                                          connect_by_root(firmware_version) root_fw,
                                          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, cg_id, firmware_version, connect_by_root(firmware_version) ORDER BY LEVEL DESC, sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/')) rn
                                   FROM   t2 t
                                   START  WITH image_prerequisite IS NULL
                                   CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR regexp_substr(firmware_version, '[^~]*') = image_prerequisite
                                       AND    PRIOR dmc_id = dmc_id
                                       AND    PRIOR cg_id = cg_id)
SELECT chain,
       root_fw,
       firmware_version AS fw,
       device_count AS cnt,
       dmc_id,
       cg_id,
       lev,
       count_within_dmcid,
       rn,
       SUM(device_count) over(PARTITION BY dmc_id, cg_id, root_fw ORDER BY lev DESC) AS cumm
FROM   t3
ORDER  BY dmc_id,
          cg_id,
          lev DESC;
```

which gives us:

```
CHAIN                                         ROOT_FW    FW                     CNT     DMC_ID CG_ID         LEV COUNT_WITHIN_DMCID         RN       CUMM
--------------------------------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ------ ---------- ------------------ ---------- ----------
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4                              RT1        RT4                     18        408 0000            4              24028          1         18
/RT1/RT2/RT3                                  RT1        RT3                     24        408 0000            3              24028          1         42
/RT1/RT2                                      RT1        RT2                     40        408 0000            2              24028          1         82
/SVP01                                        SVP01      SVP01                    4        408 0000            1              24028          1          4
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                   2109        408 0000            1              24028          1       2191
/Sanity01                                     Sanity01   Sanity01                11        408 0000            1              24028          1         11
/Sanity1                                      Sanity1    Sanity1                  1        408 0000            1              24028          1          1
/TB_HT01                                      TB_HT01    TB_HT01                  6        408 0000            1              24028          1          6
/TEST_1                                       TEST_1     TEST_1                   1        408 0000            1              24028          1          1
/TK_ST001                                     TK_ST001   TK_ST001                 5        408 0000            1              24028          1          5
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA1          1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA2          1                  2          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA3          1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA4          1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA5          1                  2          1          1
/RT1/RT2                                      RT1        RT2                      1       1422 0000            2                  7          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1       1422 0000            1                  7          1          2
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D~SU.E/SU.F/SU.G~SU.H/SU.I SU.A       SU.I                    20       3345 0000            7                 93          1         20
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D~SU.E/SU.F/SU.G~SU.H      SU.A       SU.G~SU.H               21       3345 0000            6                 93          1         41
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D~SU.E/SU.F                SU.A       SU.F                    20       3345 0000            5                 93          1         61
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D~SU.E                     SU.A       SU.D~SU.E               16       3345 0000            4                 93          1         77
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C                               SU.A       SU.C                     6       3345 0000            3                 93          1         83
/SU.A/SU.B                                    SU.A       SU.B                     5       3345 0000            2                 93          1         88
/SU.A                                         SU.A       SU.A                     5       3345 0000            1                 93          1         93
```

What this latest query does is first find out if there are firmwares that are at the same level as each other, and if so, we listagg them together (here, I've used `~` as a separator for clarity in the results - there's nothing to stop you from using the same separator as you use in the sys_connect_by_path).

Once we have that, we can do the connect by, but we need to look at just the first entry in the newly calculated firmware column (otherwise we won't find a match in the image_prerequisite column). Then it's just calculating the results in the same way the previous query did.

Comment: thank you for your help!
This query solved my problem :)

Comment: Thank you for providing decent information in your question! I wish everyone would...

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have another scenario of FW chains in input data and this query is not returning the expected results.
Please help me with the query/procedure to resolve this issue.

I have edited the question with new scenario above.
Thanks

Comment: Is there any way we can split this problem into two parts - first we can create the chain and based on that cumulative counts will be calculated.
Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Comment: Your latest expected output doesn't really make much sense - e.g. SU.D and SU.E have the same image_prerequisite, which makes them at the same level. So how come your chain has SU.E a level below SU.D?

Comment: I know this output is not making much sense.. But this is the requirement of the problem. Please help me with this!

Comment: Or is it possible that if we have multiple FW at the same level than we treat it as a single firmware_version (SU.D-SU.E)  and the device count for this one fw will be SU.D + SU.E.

Comment: Does the cumulative sum need to restart at 0 if that is the case?

Comment: If we are treating firmware_version at same level as single entity and device_count as (SU.D+SU.E) then cumulative count needs not to be reset to 0. 
then chain and cumulative will go as current behavious - the only difference will be if we have multiple fw at same level then instead of treating it as multiple records we will treat it as one firmware_version

Comment: Thanks But this query is not returning the full results.

for RT1 --RT2--RT3--RT4 and other firmware_versions as well 
Split chain results are coming as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152068/discussion-between-a-saraf-and-boneist).

Comment: When i am running this query on database table it is throwing an error
"ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long"

Comment: Please suggest any workaround to avoid this error in the query 
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long"

Comment: That is happening because during the concatenation of firmware items that are at the same level as each other, it's going over 4000 characters. You'd have to find another way of concatenating the items, such that it produces a clob rather than a varchar2 (which is limited to 4000 characters in SQL). I'll leave that as an exercise for you to do - it should be easy enough to slot into my query, instead of doing the LISTAGG. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675852/oracle-cumulative-counts-within-chain-of-records/45677092?noredirect=1#comment78424169_45677092) might help you.

Comment: I have tried the below function to use clob but it is not working
CAST(RTRIM(EXTRACT(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw", dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw.firmware_version || ',') ORDER BY dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw.firmware_version), '/dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw/text()').getclobval(),',') AS VARCHAR2(2000))

Whenever i am using XMLAGG, it requires a GROUP BY in the query and after using GROUP BY it is messing up the chain and device count.

Comment: No wonder it doesn't work, if you're casting the clob containing more than 2000 characters to a string of 2000 characters! Perhaps you mean substr?

Comment: Also, what version are you on? In 12.2, listagg has been updated to handle cases where it ends up with a string over 4000 chars - it won't output the full string, but it can be made to not error either.

Comment: I am using version older version that is why when I am using this query in my ETL package it is throwing error during LISTAGG.

Comment: You need to decide what to display in the case when there are multiple firmware versions at the same level. Do you pick just the first one and concatenate something like " and 15 others"? or just the first one? It may not be possible to do what you're after in the database - you may need to do the logic outside of the database.

Comment: Is it possible that if we have multiple firmware_version at same level then we just display the first one with an extra character to identify like (SU.A~) rather than concatenating all other. But the device_count should be same as we are doing now like the sum of all at same level.

concatenate value - "SU.A~N"
In the end of process what matters mainly is the cumulative count of devices at each level

Comment: Sure, you'd just need to use either the MIN or MAX analytic function instead of LISTAGG, depending on which firmware_version you wanted to display. Don't forget to concatenate whatever string you need to that.

Comment: MIN/MAX requires GROUP BY and when i will use GROUP by it will change the results

Comment: That's why I said "analytic function"... Hint: this is listagg as an aggregate function: `listagg(<column>, <delimiter>) within group (order by <column list>)` and this is listagg as an analytic function: `listagg(<column>, <delimiter>) within group (order by <column list> over (partition by <columns to group by> order by <columns to order by>)`. Now do you see what you need to do to switch out the LISTAGG with a MIN/MAX in my query above?

Comment: Thanks! It is returning expected results